select consecutive duplicate records from the table
This is my sample record set.
I want to SELECT (DELETE after confirmation) all the consecutive duplicate records having the same lid, same sid, same stype, same bid and 0 or null noOfDays. The lastest record should be preserved and all earlier ones should be removed.



rid
lid
sid
stype
uid
urole
bid
rdate
ndays




1
123
106963
P
0
M
5243
2024-06-24 00:00:00
1


2
123
106977
P
0
M
5243
2024-06-24 00:00:00
1


3
123
114234
P
0
M
5243
2024-06-24 00:00:00
2


4
123
106973
P
0
M
5243
2024-06-25 00:00:00
9


5
123
106975
P
0
M
5243
2024-07-03 00:00:00
1


6
123
106964
P
0
M
5243
2024-07-03 00:00:00
1


7
123
107394
P
0
M
5243
2024-07-03 00:00:00
1


8
123
106964
P
0
M
5243
2024-07-03 00:00:00
3


9
123
107394
P
0
M
5243
2024-07-05 00:00:00
4


10
123
107395
P
0
M
5243
2024-07-08 00:00:00
25


11
123
106964
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-01 00:00:00
1


12
123
107394
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-01 00:00:00
2


13
123
107395
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-02 00:00:00
0


14
123
107395
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-02 00:00:00
0


15
123
107395
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-02 00:00:00
7


16
123
106971
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-08 00:00:00
5


17
123
106974
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-12 00:00:00
1


18
123
106976
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-12 00:00:00
3


19
123
106980
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-14 00:00:00
0



Expected Output for the give dataset:



rid
lid
sid
stype
uid
urole
bid
rdate
ndays




13
123
107395
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-02 00:00:00
0


14
123
107395
P
0
M
5243
2024-08-02 00:00:00
0



Explanation:
Rows with rid 13, 14 and 15 have the same lid, same sid, same stype, same bid and 0 noOfDays. Also they are coming one after another in sequence so I want to keep the latest (rid 15) and remove the other two (rid 13 and 14).

"Consecutive" has no meaning in SQL.  SQL tables are, by definition, not stored in any order.  Are you saying you want to delete all duplicated records?  Are "lid" and "sid" enough to establish a duplicate?

Your input data seems to have unique rid, but the output has duplicated rid=1. Shouldn't they be rid=10 and rid=13?

@TimRoberts I think they mean to use rid as the determiner for "consecutive". Their output contains the records from the original rid=10 and rid=13-15. The latter 3 consecutive rows are merged into one.

If you're using MySQL 8.x, look into using the LAG() window function to detect consecutive duplicates.

@Barmar sorry mybad, updated with correct rid.

@TimRoberts the criteria to determine duplicates are the conditions I mentioned later same lid, same sid, same stype, same bid and 0 or null noOfDays. But I don't want all these duplicates to be removed, I want only those duplicate records that are coming immediately one after another

@Nick great, that determines duplicates. but what determines consecutive?

General hint: Use unique keys to prevent duplicates from the start. Example: unique key (rid,lid)

In your example data rid=15 value for ndays (I'm assuming it's what you mention as noOfDays) is 7, not 0 as you said.

Why is it 13 and 14 in the desired result, not 10 and 13?

@Barmar because there is no other sid between 13 and 14 but there are 2 different sid's between 10 and 13.

@ysth You are actually right even I figured there is no fool proof way for me to decide what will be called consecutive.. so I wrote a script to so it rather than a query. Thanks for the help.

If a script can do it, then there is a way, and it should be possible to do in sql

So in the script, i fetched all the lids. Then loped over them to fetch the records for each lid from the above table ordering it by rdate. then looped over this recordset and if two iterations had the same sid then kept the 1st one and removed all others

Select Consecutive Duplicate Records
The following query will help you select consecutive duplicate records, excluding the latest one (highest rid).
SELECT *
FROM your_table t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(rid) AS latest_rid, lid, sid, stype, bid
    FROM your_table
    WHERE (ndays = 0 OR ndays IS NULL)
    GROUP BY lid, sid, stype, bid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.lid = t2.lid
      AND t1.sid = t2.sid
      AND t1.stype = t2.stype
      AND t1.bid = t2.bid
      AND t1.rid < t2.latest_rid
ORDER BY t1.lid, t1.sid, t1.rdate;

Confirm and Delete the Selected Records
Once you've confirmed the records to delete, you can replace the SELECT * statement with DELETE to remove them:
DELETE t1
FROM your_table t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(rid) AS latest_rid, lid, sid, stype, bid
    FROM your_table
    WHERE (ndays = 0 OR ndays IS NULL)
    GROUP BY lid, sid, stype, bid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.lid = t2.lid
      AND t1.sid = t2.sid
      AND t1.stype = t2.stype
      AND t1.bid = t2.bid
      AND t1.rid < t2.latest_rid;

This DELETE command will remove all consecutive duplicates while keeping only the latest one in each sequence. Ensure to back up your data before running this to avoid accidental data loss.

Looks like you need in the next query:
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (lid, sid, stype, uid, urole, bid, rdate)
WHERE t1.ndays = 0
  AND t1.rid = t2.rid - 1

